# In python map certain functions to another function that take their name as a parameter

Tags: python

I am trying to use reflection or some similar concept in python to have a set of function calls get mapped to a different function call, but passes the name of the original function with the new call.
For example:

I have a list of the function names `['func1','func2','func3']`

`func1(data)` becomes `mapped_func('func1', data)`

`func2(data)` becomes `mapped_func('func2', data)`

`func3(data1, data2)` becomes `mapped_func('func3', data1, data2)`

The list of functions gets loaded from a database and a user can add to the list. Essentially the mapped_func looks up a more complicated set of actions based off the name and then executes those. I was hoping to use 'reflection' so more complicated things like:

`func1(func2(data))/func3(data1,data2)`

Would just work because they would be mapped accordingly and the python interpreter would essentially make this:

`mapped_func('func1',mapped_func('func2',data))/mapped_func('func3',data1,data2)`

Comment: how about using `eval` https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/eval?

Comment: wouldn't `my_func.__name__` satisfy this? Or could you provide a minimal and verifiable sample code so we can help you better?

Comment: I was trying to think about how to provide sample code but couldn't think of what to provide. I don't know how to to do it or even what the write tools to use are. I was looking at ast and astor. eval doesn't really buy me anything other than I could do a ton of string manipulation on my own. But I feel that gets complicated very fast if you are trying to find and replace lots of different things with all the potential edge cases.